# ios compare boolean from json

Tags: ios

I got a boolean value from a json object using dictionary. at console, I can see 0 or 1.
But my comparision always return true.

```
BOOL *result =[dictionary valueForKey:@"result"];

        if (result == YES) {

            [parser release];
        }
        else {
            errorLbl.text = @"Login failed";
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

have you tried adding a boolValue at the end of `[dictionary valueForKey:@"result"]boolValue]`;

Comment: Here's what I've done: BOOL *result=[[dictonary objectForKey:@"result"] boolValue]; instead of the result line you have

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the value from the dictionary. You can't translate it directly to a `BOOL *` (`BOOL` pointer).

Suppose you get a `NSString*` from your dictionary, you can do:

```
NSString *result = [dictionary valueForKey:@"result"];
if ([result boolValue]) {
    [parser release];
} else {
    errorLbl.text = @"Login failed";
}
```

Assuming you can use [`boolValue` message](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) with your protocol.

Comment: @user974459: `boolValue` is a message you can pass to the `NSString` class. Check out the link I put.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below code, I got

```
BOOL success = [[jsonDict objectForKey:@"success"] boolValue];
if (success == YES){ //Do some stuff } else{ //Do some stuff }
```